# Button to update records in a database (da.Update(ds,...)

Tags: database, vb.net-2010

I'm having a bit of an issue with my code. I have connected the database and am able to view records, add records and even delete records.

However, I cannot get the update button working at all. I keep getting an "InvalidOperationException" error.

```vb
Private Sub btnAmend_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAmend.Click
    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

    ds.Tables("Contacts").Rows(inc).Item(1) = txtFirstName.Text
    ds.Tables("Contacts").Rows(inc).Item(2) = txtSurname.Text
    da.Update(ds, "Contacts")
    MsgBox("Data updated")
End Sub
```